# How to add multiple groups in to an Azure API Management service product using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-api-management

I want to attach multiple groups for a single product in Azure API Management service from Terraform.

Terraform registry only allows to attach single group by its name. Is there any way to attach multiple groups such as Developers, Guests as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_product_group" "example" {
  product_id          = "test_product"
  group_name          = "developers"
  api_management_name = "test-api-management"
  resource_group_name = "test-rg"
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `count` for `for_each`?

Comment: @Marcin yeah, this works for me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with **Marcin**, You can make use of [**`for-each metadata argument`**](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each) in your code to create multiple Azure APIM management service Product group like below:-

**Official Terraform [Document1:](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_product_group) [Document2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_product)-**

**`My main.tf code:-`**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.74.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "siliconrg5r"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "silicon5r-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"

  sku_name = "Developer_1"
}

variable "group_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["developers", "guests"]
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "example" {
  product_id            = "test-product"
  api_management_name   = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  display_name          = "Test Product"
  subscription_required = true
  subscriptions_limit = 100
  approval_required     = true
  published             = true
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_product_group" "example" {
  for_each = toset(var.group_names)

  product_id          = azurerm_api_management_product.example.product_id
  group_name          = each.value
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


output "api_management_url" {
  value = azurerm_api_management.example.portal_url
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**APIM instance with Product deployed successfully:-**

[image]

**Product groups with guests and developer created successfully:-**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. This works for me.